# What's the shortest distance that can be travelled via Stargate?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, stargate-universe

The question is pretty simple: what's the minimum distance that can be travelled via a Stargate?  I know two stargates cannot operate in close proximity, such as on the same planet, as one Stargate will override the other, rendering it inoperable while the other is in use. But could you use a Stargate to create a wormhole between Mars and Earth (if there was one on Mars) for example?

My memory is a bit rusty on SGU, but it seemed the Destiny was pretty close to some of the planets they gated to from the Destiny after dropping out of FTL.

Comment: Dang. I didn't find that question when I did my search. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Gonna go ahead and say this is a duplicate of [What is the smallest distance possible that two stargets are able to dial one another?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39540/what-is-the-smallest-distance-possible-that-two-stargates-are-able-to-dial-one-a)

Shortest distance is technically 0, since on occasions like "1969" a stargate can connect to itself in a different point in the timeline with the help of a Solar Flare.

Besides that, the only time we ever see one gate override another is when a new Stargate is in orbit of a planet. So going purely by Stargate canon, then as long as you're on another planet, you're far enough away. So yes, you could have stargates on Venus, Earth AND Mars and they wouldn't interfere with each other. In theory.

Comment: Distance relative to what? If it's relative to the sun, the planet moves. If it's relative to the centre of the galaxy, the sun moves. So the distance would never be zero.

Comment: Ok, then shortest distance is however far away the 1969 gate was in space from the 1999 gate when SG-1 walked through it. The episode aired February 3rd, 1999, so we'll take that as the date they stepped through. The episode is mainly set in August 4th, 1969. This puts the Earth pretty much the other end of it's orbit, making the distance about 186 Million Miles, which is still less than the distance between Earth and Mars at 249 Million Miles.

Comment: You are forgetting the spin of the Galaxy (given that this network of Gates can only operate within the Milky way with the set of chevrons used). Just put it down to a quantum lock or something and move on ;)

Comment: Also just realised that the 1969 episode is the only occasion of the travellers actually returning to the same gate they passed through, even with time travel involved. All other episodes show them travelling through time, but still arriving at the destination, rather than the place they left. Atlantis did this when Shephard got propelled into the future, for example. So my example could well be false canonically anyway.

Comment: Would distance travelled 4th dimensionally (thru time) count as distance as well?

Comment: No, because distance is a numerical measure of how far apart two objects are in physical space. Time is not a spatial dimension, it is a temporal one. As such, time is not included in measurements of distance, as indicated by its measurement in seconds as opposed to meters.

Comment: But this case isn't *two gates* but two different space time points intersected by *the same gate*.